# File versioning sync for Windows

Tags: windows, file, synchronization, rsync

I want to monitor a folder for changes and save different versions of files that are being changed. I don't want to synchronize changes but rather maintain a passive repository that records all changes to a folder. Is there any good freeware program to do this?

I cannot setup a repository in the folder because I have only read-only permissions to it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VBackup](http://www.fileviewer.com/vbackup/index.html) does the trick!

From the website:

> VBackup is a command line program for Windows that is used to make
>   backup copies of directories.
>
> It is similar in functionality to XCOPY and ROBOCOPY, however, VBackup
>   implements file versioning. This means that you can not only restore
>   files from the latest backup, but you can also restore them from any
>   previous backup.
>
> VBackup Version 0.7 (Freeware) Copyright (c) 2010 Charles Prineas. All
>   Rights Reserved.
>
> Usage:   VBackup Source Destination [options]
>
> ```
>        Source   The directory to back up
>   Destination   The directory where Source will be backed up to :: :: Options: ::
>            /?   Display this help screen
>            /C   Continue with backup if an error occurs
>            /R   Restore the latest backup
>           /RP   Restore previous backup (you will be prompted with available backups)
>  /RP:YYYYMMDD   Restore backup made on YYYY/MM/DD
>            /L   List Only - do not backup any files
>            /Q   Quiet mode - suppress output
>           /NS   Do not backup subdirectories
>          /LSK   Log skipped files
>          /LUN   Log unchanged files
>          /NBS   Do not create a backup set
> ```
>
> /IF file [file]   Only backup files matching name/mask   /XF file
>   [file]   Exclude files matching name/mask
>       /ID dir [dir]   Only backup directory matching name/mask
>       /XD dir [dir]   Exclude directory matching name/mask
>
> /IFV file [file]   Only make version backup of files matching
>   name/mask  /XFV file [file]   Do not make version backup of files
>   matching name/mask
>
> ```
>     /MAX:size   Do not back up files greater than size
>    /MAXV:size   Do not make version backups of files greater than size
>
>    /NAME:name   Give the backup a meaningful name (which can be used when restoring)
>     /LOG:file   Output to log file (overwrite existing log)
>    /LOG+:file   Output to log file (append to existing log)
>  /UNILOG:file   Output to Unicode log file (overwrite existing log)
> /UNILOG+:file   Output to Unicode log file (append to existing log) :: :: Examples: ::
>    VBackup C:\Source D:\Backups\Source /XF *.tmp *.bak /XD Release Debug /NAME:"Version 11"
>    VBackup /R D:\Backups\Source C:\Source.Restore
>    VBackup /R /NAME:"Version 11" D:\Backups\Source "C:\Source.Version 11" :: :: Notes: ::
>    Use quotes around names if they contain spaces
>    Only ONE source directory can be specified
>    File names (or masks) must be passed using /IF
>    You can only restore to an empty (or non-existent) directory :: :: Contact: ::
>    http://www.fileviewer.com/vbackup
> ```